# Delphi XE7 + Android Error -> No mapping for the Unicode character exists

Tags: android, json, delphi, indy, zlib

Мy program for android should get data from the server as json when to perform under Win32 works good, and in android error!

PHP:

```
$err = array();
$data = array('id'=>1,'name'=>'test','info'=>'1234');
$inf = array('data' => $data ,'error' => $err);
$json = json_encode($inf);
$json = gzencode(trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$json )),9);
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
header("content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8");
header("cache-control: must-revalidate");
header("expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time()+60)." GMT" );
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen( $json ) );
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
echo $json;
```

Delphi XE7:

```
    uses ..., IdCompressorZLib;

    var
      LoginInfo: TStringList;
      Response: TStringStream;
      data string;
      http: TIdHTTP;
      cook: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;


        http:= TIdHTTP.Create();
        http.ConnectTimeout:= 30000;
        http.Compressor:= TIdCompressorZLib.Create();
        cook:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
        http.IOHandler:= cook;

        LoginInfo := TStringList.Create;
        Response := TStringStream.Create('');
        LoginInfo.Add('cmd=get');
        http.Post('https://site/api/get.php',LoginInfo,Response);
        http.Disconnect;
        data:= Response.DataString;
        Memo1.Lines.Add(data);
```

For win32 work good!
If run to Android show error: 
*"No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page"*, mpirically established that an error occurs in 
*data:= Response.DataString;*

If transfer data without compression is working well in android :(

Grateful for the help!

Comment: Debugging tip: You're clearly not receiving what you expected to, so find out what you're getting instead. Whatever you're getting isn't a valid string, so fetch the result into something else instead, like a TFileStream, and then inspect the contents of the file.

Comment: Opp! I find bug-> Response := TStringStream.Create('',TEncoding.UTF8);